# how find sum of an array, for a specific range of keys

Tags: php, arrays

```
//input array
$array = {
          2 => 5,
          4 => 1,
          8 => 3,
          9 => 2,
}
```

want sum of key for a specific period like 1-5, 6-10

need output like array {1-5 => 6 ,6-10 => 5}

Comment: You're aware that the code you have written is not even a valid PHP array right? If you want to use the shorthand syntax it is square brackets `[]` not curly braces `{}` and will only work for PHP 5.4.X and above.

Comment: i need a code, that not use foreach

Comment: Related question: [PHP sum all values of a numeric array between min and max two keys performatively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72486200/2943403)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.. Not a rocket science..

```
function sumArray($array, $min, $max) {
   $sum = 0;
   foreach ($array as $k => $a) {
      if ($k >= $min && $k <= $max) {
         $sum += $a;
      }
   }
   return $sum;
}

echo sumArray($array, 1, 5);
```

```
# this is your answer
$sum = array_sum(array_slice($array, $from, $to));
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you might want to see all groups/ranges represented in the result and that some data might not qualify for any group, I've extended the sample data to show these considerations.

Use a conditionally broken nested loop with minimum and maximum numbers which will add amounts to respective groups/ranges.

`array_map()` is used to establish a `0` value for all declared groups/ranges.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rGAZL))

```
$array = [
    2 => 5,
    4 => 1,
    8 => 3,
    0 => 17,
    9 => 2,
    11 => 67
];

$ranges = [
    '1-5' => ['min' => 1, 'max' => 5],
    '6-10' => ['min' => 6, 'max' => 10],
    '1000-5000' => ['min' => 1000, 'max' => 5000],
];

$result = array_map(fn() => 0, $ranges);
foreach ($array as $num => $amount) {
    foreach ($ranges as $rangeName => ['min' => $min, 'max' => $max]) {
        if ($num >= $min && $num <= $max) {
            $result[$rangeName] += $amount;
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '1-5' => 6,
  '6-10' => 5,
  '1000-5000' => 0,
)
```